# Set a bounty the wrong way

Tags: support, bounties

I set a bounty for [one of my questions](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/24511/display-menu-items-deeper-as-second-level-show-as-expanded-doesnt-actually-ex). Accidentally I set the bounty as something in the likes of 'answer doesn't give enough details'. In reality the answer is on the wrong track entirely so I would like to reset my bounty to something that says I need a different answer.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've removed the bounty so you can set it properly.